# Does Windows 64bit has 64bit version of windows apis?

Tags: c++, windows, api, 64-bit, convention

Old 32bit windows provides 32bit windows api, most of them have calling convention of 'WINAPI', which is a macro defined from '__stdcall'.

Now with 64bit，calling convention has been unified to Microsoft 'x64 calling convention': (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions)

> My question is:

Does 64bit windows also provide a set of windows api 64bit, without any 'WINAPI' indicators?

If so, how to make old applications be compatible and compiled into windows 64bit version? There'll be problem dealing with old calling conventions.

Comment: This is only an imaginary problem.  There is only one declaration for a winapi function, it works both in a 32-bit and 64-bit target.  There is no problem with the calling convention, WINAPI is a macro that resolves to nothing when you target x64.  Even if the compiler encounters __stdcall it is still not a problem since it doesn't do anything.

Comment: __stdcall doesn't have anything related with x64 vs x86.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation